# DRF return JsonResponse from another function

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to return the `JsonResponse` from another function but I get the following error from DRF:

> AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or
> `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a
> `<class 'NoneType'>`

Here is my code

```
class SignedURL(GenericViewSet):
    queryset = fileUpload.objects.all()
    serializer_class = fileUploadSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        function1(request)
        function2(request)
        function3(request) <-- must quit here if this function has an error and return the JSONresponse of this function.
        function4(request)


def function1(request):

        return JsonResponse(
            {
                "message": "Pass",
            },
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
```

How can I return the `JsonResponse` from another function without writing return JsonResponse in the `def create` itself?

### Further clarification:

I have ten different `functions` with ten different `JsonResponse`.

ie, `function2`,`function3`...`function10`. If, for example, `function 4` fails, I would like to return the `JsonResponse` immediately from that function and not proceed further with the other functions after `function 4` within the create call.

Comment: Anyway, you should return something in the .create() method. For example
```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        response = function1(request)
        return response

```
Now you got JsonResponse from function() call and you can return it in another method.

Comment: but  if `response` in `function1` is failed, then it will proceed to all the other `functions`, or?

Answer (score 0):

Your `function1` currently only `return`s a JsonResponse without any error checking. This will cause the script to stop and no further code being executed.

It will not proceed to any other function calls within the `create` method.

Your code in its current state should have the effect you are looking for. Have you imported `JsonResponse`?

Comment: In "normal" python that will be the case. But In DRF it will return the error because it wants the JSONresponse in the create and not from another function.

Comment: Yes because there needs to be at least 1 response coming from the view and what if none of these functions returns one? DRF can't know, so you have to define a default response in the view, while returning a response from another function is also allowed.

Comment: Please try it, you will see it will return only create response and never the function response no matter what.

Comment: I just realized the issue. because your function `return`s this JsonResponse but your view will ignore it unless you either save its value and do further checking down the line and finally `return` it in the view or just do a `return function1(request)` which is definitely not what you want to do because it will stop executing the code you have beyond that point!

Comment: Exactly! I am stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

In general it sounds a bit anorthodox what you are trying to implement. In any case, you can capture the response of all functions and return it from the `create` method.

But in any case, you need some error handling, either inside your function (most likely, since you want to return a `JSONResponse`) or in the `create` method (e.g. using `try`/`except`) which seems it's not close to what you want to achieve, since you won't have something returned from each function that fails (unless you handle exceptions in EACH function).

So maybe something like:

```
class SignedURL(GenericViewSet):
    queryset = fileUpload.objects.all()
    serializer_class = fileUploadSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        result1, is_success1 = function1(request)
        if is_success1 is False:
            # Quit here if this function has an error and return the JSONresponse of this function
            return result1

        # similar checks below
        result2, is_success2 = function2(request)
        result3, is_success3 = function3(request)
        ...
```

And

```
def function1(request):
    try:
        return 1 / 0, True
    except:
        return JsonResponse(
            {
                "message": "ERROR HAPPENED!"
            },
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        ), False
```

Comment: I would argue the proposed solution is even more entagled. Because now I have to repeat this across 10 functions and capture the success/fail and have return checked after every function. You say it is unorthodox, what is the alternatives if all functions are are unique and act on different part of the data

Comment: this is another question though. I agree that also is not the proper way to do this 10 times. You should use a loop or something else. In your original question, you asked a specific thing, for which I tried to recommend a specific solution. If you want to also run this with a for-loop or a better solution, you'd better ask specifically for it (perhaps in another question?)